# How would I go about choosing a particular file path for visual studio to read and write to other than the debug folder

Tags: vb.net, file, storage

The problem is that I am unable to find a way to edit files that are not in the debug folder of the program that I am creating,

I've tried editing the part in the `File.WriteAllLines` function in visual studio:

```
Private Sub btnFinalise_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFinalise.Click
    Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(Character_Upload.CharName & ".txt")
    Dim lines2() As String = File.ReadAllLines("Character_List.txt")
    Dim linecount = File.ReadAllLines("Character_List.txt").Length
    lines2(linecount) = Character_Upload.CharName & ";" & Environment.NewLine
    File.WriteAllLines("Character_List.txt", lines2)
    File.WriteAllLines(Character_Upload.CharName & ".txt", lines)
End Sub
```

I would like to go into a folder called "Characters", but it will only create in the debug file and not interact with the aforementioned folder

Comment: When you deploy, if your app is installed in `Program Files`, you cannot write there. You could use the provided `Application.LocalUserAppDataPath` or `Application.UserAppDataPath` (which will give you a path to the `AppData.Local` or `AppData.Roaming` paths plus the `CompanyName/ProductName/Version`) to store your data. Add Folder names to this path and use `Directory.CreateDirectory()` to create the paths you need.

Comment: I think this line will give you and index out of range error. `lines2(linecount) = Character_Upload.CharName & ";" & Environment.NewLine` Say there are 7 lines in the array. The indexes are 0-6. The length of the array is 7 but that is outside the range of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim lines2() As String = File.ReadAllLines("Character_List.txt")
    Dim linecount = File.ReadAllLines("Character_List.txt").Length
```

is

```
      File.ReadAllLines(PATH As String)
```

so if you make File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\Character_List.txt") it will work too.

Also for interactive multi files opening

```
Try
    Dim OpenDialog As New OpenFileDialog()
    OpenDialog.Multiselect = True
    OpenDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    OpenDialog.FilterIndex = 1
    OpenDialog.RestoreDirectory = True
    If OpenDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OpenDialog.FileName) Then 
            Dim folder As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenDialog.FileName)
            If IO.Directory.Exists(folder) Then
               'stuff here

            Else
                Exit Sub 
            End If
        End If
    End If
Catch ex as Exception
'exception handling

Finally

End Try
```

edited as clarification to comment:

```
Dim workingpath As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() 'gets location of working program
Directory.CreateDirectory(workingpath & "\Characters") 'create folder in that location
```

then in your code you can use it like this:

```
Dim lines2() As String = File.ReadAllLines("Characters\Character_List.txt")
```

or even like this

```
Dim CharFolder as String = Directory.CreateDirectory(workingpath & "\Characters") 'create folder in that location
Dim lines2() As String = File.ReadAllLines(CharFolder & "\Character_List.txt")
```

for getting working path you can also use

```
Application.StartupPath' gets path of directory that stores your exe file
```

or

```
Application.UserAppDataPath ' gets path of directory for the application data
```

or just try with any other

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectory(Application.ExecutablePath)    
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()    
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)    
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
Application.StartupPath
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

depending on situation might provide different paths

Comment: I'm not trying to open multiple files at the same time, im trying to read and write a file in a folder in my debug file "\bin\Debug\Characters" to store and read files from there

Comment: Dim workingpath As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() 'gets location of working program
        Directory.CreateDirectory(workingpath & "\Characters") 'create folder in that location

then in  
Dim lines2() As String = File.ReadAllLines("Characters\Character_List.txt")

Comment: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` does **not** give you the application's path. You can use `Application.StartupPath`, `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` or `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)` if you need the `file:///` version.

Comment: @Jimi Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() - gets **current** application **working** path. If he's not using other functions or subs that change that dir it will always give working application directory (eg. where exe file is). In that case it is bin\debug path that he needs

Comment: It will never give you the application path when your application is out in the *real world* (outside Visual Studio). `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` can be anything.

Comment: it won't if hes using default settings.
From ms database:
_The current directory is distinct from the original directory, **which is the one from which the process was started**._
so if user starts app from start menu, with default publish settings it will give dir for exe file or for webapps iss dir

Comment: You should read the Docs about `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. Any application can cause a directory to become the current. Your application doesn't just exist when it's started. It has to survive beyond that point. If you use that method, it won't.

Comment: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() **may** (ok I'm using this word) return you path for working application (and it will in like most cases if your project is simple) and if you don't change it will be the same. Now for testing i made one app that Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("C:\Temp") and run another one that uses Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() and it gives me exe running path. So what I'm missing here? Also tried -> making shortcut, and copying published project to another location and even end code for OpenFileDialog and still gives me right path. How i can force it to give me different pth

Comment: @jimi just don't take it as attack i consider myself a barely junior at vb.net so i dont know what i'm missing here.

Comment: Why would I consider this as *hostile*? Anyway, this is not related to VB.Net: this is a .Net method, available to all .Net languages. Read the remarks setion of [GetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory) (1st reason). In the .Net source code of [GetCurrentDirectory()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,1078), you see it calls [NewGetCurrentDirectory()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,1138). Which then calls a Win32 function (from `winbase.h`)...

Comment: [GetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) see the remarks section there (2nd reason). Any part of your code can set the Process's `CurrentDirectory`. Any external application can also do this, depending on the type of the application. Shell APIs can also cause a change in the current directory (FolderBrowserDialog/FileDialog) (3rd reason). You cannot trust that *current* actually is a specific path. If you do, you'll have a problem, sooner or later. But you have the methods I previously listed.